# Re-validate field after changing input

Tags: javascript, html, validation

We are using HTML form validation (and we explicitly do NOT want do use jQuery validate plugin...). Currently I am able to mark invalid/empty fields after Submit. I do it this way:

```
if(document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener('invalid', function(e){
        e.target.className += ' invalid';
    }, true);
}
```

But the marking remains after the user enters information to a field. How can I remove the className, let's say, onBlur?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can just add the following CSS classes:

```
input:invalid:focus,
input.invalid{
    border: solid 1px #f00;    /* red border */
}
input:valid {
    border: 1px solid #ced4da; /* reset to default border color */
}
```

At least this seems to work.

Are there any smarter solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `blur` event within the `invalid` event handler like so:

```
document.addEventListener("invalid", function(e) {
    const oldClassName = e.target.className;
    e.target.className += "-invalid";
    e.target.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
        e.target.className = oldClassName;
    }, { once: true });
});
```

The `{ once: true }` option at the end ensures that the event listener gets taken off once the blur happens.

Answer (score 0):

The browser automatically adds/removes the `:invalid` pseudo selector for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid, just style the form fields as you would for the regular case (not invalid) and invalid case (using the `:invalid` selector)